# How could I optimise this js event?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the img src based on what button I have clicked.

My current approach is to add event listeners to each img id and change then change the image of the top img tag. The issue with this apporach is that I will have a lot of repetetive code especially when im adding more buttons.

So i would like someone to give advice or show me a different and better approach to do this. Im requesting help in only native javascript. Thanks.

```js
document.getElementById("human").addEventListener("click", e => {
  document.getElementById('imageChange').src = "dir/images/human.png";
})
document.getElementById("dwarf").addEventListener("click", e => {
  document.getElementById('imageChange').src = "dir/images/dwarf.png";
})
document.getElementById("elf").addEventListener("click", e => {
  document.getElementById('imageChange').src = "dir/images/elf.png";
})
```

```html
<img id="imageChange" src="dir/images/human.png" alt="">

<div class="buttonContainer">
  <img src="../dir/images/race/human_male.png" id="human" class="race human_container"></img>
  <img src="../dir/images/race/dwarf_male.png" id="dwarf" class="race dwarf_container"></img>
  <img src="../dir/images/race/elf_male.png" id="elf" class="race elf_container"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try running your snippet before you posted it?  The images don't load.

Comment: Add only a single listener to `#buttonContainer`, detect the clicked image from `e.target` and apply its manipulated src to `#imageChange` or build the path using the id of the clicked image.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you, if u have a minute could you show a small sample of what it would look like, im unsure of how i should detect what one i clicked and manipulate the src based on that.

Comment: It looks like dfsq has already answered the question. Though you've to manipulate the path, since it looks like the new images are coming from a different folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, that having multiple event handler is not a good solution. You can have single one attached to the common container. Something like this:

```js
document.querySelector(".buttonContainer").addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    document.getElementById('imageChange').src = e.target.src    
  }
})
```

```css
.buttonContainer img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<img id="imageChange" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/oxygen/64x64/mimetypes/unknown.png" alt="">

<div class="buttonContainer">
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-network-7/50/4-64.png" id="human" class="race human_container" />
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-network-7/50/6-64.png" id="dwarf" class="race dwarf_container" />
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-network-7/50/29-64.png" id="elf" class="race elf_container" />
</div>
```

It is necessary to check event target `e.target.tagName === 'IMG'` because click event bound like this might get triggered by clicking on elements other than images (so with no `src`).

Comment: Thank you, this what was i was looking for, i just didnt have any idea about how to use event target. What you provided worked in whole besides that it replaced the src of the img tag with the same as the button  you clicked so i changed it up abit so fetch the id instead and  apply that to the src i wanted to get the correct img up. Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know what you want to change the image to why not add it in the html as a data- attribute then just replace the current src with the data- value?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var clickables = document.querySelectorAll('.race');

function showImage(e) {
  var src = e.target.src;
  document.getElementById('imageChange').src = src;
}

for (var i = clickables.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  clickables[i].addEventListener('click', showImage);
}
```

```css
.buttonContainer img {max-width: 100px}
```

```html
<img id="imageChange" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ed/Nyan_cat_250px_frame.PNG" alt=""/>

<div class="buttonContainer">
  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/nyancat/images/f/ff/Mexinyan.gif/revision/latest?cb=20150409011153" id="human" class="race human_container"/>
  <img src="http://www.nyan.cat/cats/original.gif" id="dwarf" class="race dwarf_container"/>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ed/Nyan_cat_250px_frame.PNG" id="elf" class="race elf_container"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("race");
for(var i = 0; i < imageNodes.length; i++){
   imageNodes[i].addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
   const imageId = e.target.id;
   document.getElementById('imageChange').src = 'dir/images/' + imageId + '.png';

   })
}
```